# How use html context sensitive help with Delphi 2007 - the basics

Tags: delphi, chm

I use Help & Manual to create web help (HTML) files.  I would like to link this to my Delphi 2007 application so that it pops up when users press the F1 key, and ideally, to pop up to a context sensitive spot.

This is what I've tried:

Adding the HTMLHelpViewer unit to the uses clause of the main form.
Setting the HelpFile property to the name of the index.htm file.
Setting the OnHelp event (this event doesn't get fired on F1, btw).

I also have searched Stack Overflow and other web links to try to find the steps to accomplish this, and while I find clues, I cannot seem to find a step by step way of accomplishing this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to set HelpContex or HelpKeyword properties. The help is only invoked if there is control with HelpContex <> 0 or HelpKeyword <> ''.

Comment: Thanks, setting the helpcontext property on one of the components causes it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of [Help & Manual](http://www.ec-software.com/products_hm_overview.html), but as a commercial application with a [dedicated support forum](http://www.ec-software.com/support_forum.html) you may find help there if we don't come up with what you need.  Here are some links that may help:

Their [online help system](http://www.helpandmanual.com/help/) has [general info on context-sensitive help](http://www.helpandmanual.com/help/hm_ref_contextpop.htm) and specific info on [application calls to webhelp](http://www.helpandmanual.com/help/hm_advanced_contexthelp_browsercalls.htm).

See ["All about help files in Borland Delphi" on this page](http://www.ec-software.com/support_tutorials.html).

There are H&M-specific Delphi components [available here for free download](http://www.ec-software.com/downloads_delphi.html).

Hope this is a start for you.

Comment: Thanks, I did try looking in the forum and at the links you mention, but unfortunately, I was not able to find the answers to my question posted here.